# move one div to put beside other divs on click of other divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I have a Div in which there is a lot of other elements like (for ease of understanding using inline-styles)

```
<div id="MainItemList" style="width:300px; height:50px;">
     <h4>This is a long content div</h4>
     <ul> <-- A Long List of Li --> </ul> 
     <p>Click on an list item</p>
     <other divs>...
</div>
```

And then there is a dynamic series of other divs and I want to make my *MainItemList* div to be positioned just below any div I click. Like

```
<div id="DynamicDivs">
   <div id="Dyn1"></div>
   <div id="Dyn2"></div>
   <div id="Dyn3"></div>
   <div id="Dyn4"></div> //And so one
</div>
```

So, now when I click on Dyn1 then my *MainItemList* div should be placed below Dyn1 div. I tried it with Jquery something like

```
var MainListDiv = '<div id="MinItemList"'>...A lot of Elements..</div>;

$(document).on('click','#DynamicDivs div', function()
{
    $(this).append(MainListDiv);
});

$(document).on('onmouseout','#DynamicDivs div', function()
{
    //Check and remove
    $('#MainListDiv').remove();
});
```

but in this way everytime a user clicks on such a div, a long code is ran to append a lot of stuff into it and remove it when user moves out. On PCs it isn't a big issue but on mobile devices it gets to much slow and that is making everything worse and worse.

What can be the trick to do so? I have made my above code running for 1 month and now it is being a headache when user complains.

Actually there is a list of some kind of pictures and icons on which user clicks then that item is appended to dynamic div and *MainListItem* must has to be just below Dynamic div so user click and be removed when onmouseout from that.

In my JQuery code everytime div is created and removed. *MainItemList* div is created on page load and is permanent (created once on page load but hidden) so it just has to be become visible and moved under any div user click and hide when mouseout? And one more thing which is making matter even worse is that when page scrolls, moves Dynamic Divs that's important :(

Comment: At least for me, it's very difficult to grasp the idea. || It is often a good idea to hide elements visually, rather than destructively get rid of something only to bring it back again. || I think the question you have to ask yourself is: "Can the code be loaded on page load?" Because I sure don't know. If you can, you just hide the parent of that element group with css `#MinItemList { display: none; }` and replace your jquery `.append()` with `.show()` and the `.remove()` with `.hide()`.

Comment: @Joonas what you are saying is same like I currently doing. Only difference will come that it will hide instead removing but yet It will have to append everytime user clicks on divs. And other thing is that code cannot be loaded as I said there is a dynamic series of divs means divs are created dynamically.

Comment: It's not the same, because in that idea the code is generated on page load once. || You are saying the divs are created dynamically, yes, I get it, but do they need to be? Are the div contents generated based on which element is clicked?, or something?

Comment: @Joonas YES divs need to be generated dynamically off-course. And div content is not generated based on anything but dynamic divs already have a lot loaded from servers. And about code loaded on page load, I already said in my last para please see after _"Can there be an..."_

Comment: Why are you asking these questions when you already know the answers? || "Can there be an idea to make this MainItemList div permanent." Well, as you told me: "YES divs need to be generated dynamically off-course." || This doesn't exactly leave much wiggle room, I hope you realize that. If content needs to be created on click, then no, it can't be created on page load. It's as simple as that. Of course if only some things within those elements are generated on click, you could generate the main structure on page load, and just fill in the blanks on click.

Comment: Oh man either you do not understand the question or I cannot make you understand while I have clearly said that there are 2 divs one which is permenant (created on page load) and rest are dynamic. the one which is permanent has to be moved and adjusted according to dynamically created divs. What's the thing you don't understand?

Comment: Nothing in your question makes any sense.

Comment: And will not make if you don't want to

Comment: I wanted to, right up until the point you started saying that you already know the answers to the questions you are asking.

Comment: I didn't say at all I know the answers not at all. I tried really hard to put my problem in front of you for better understanding but my luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, unhiding #MainListItem and giving it a fixed position next to the hovered-over div should do the trick, paying care to provide a correct 'top' value. The complicated part is figuring what a correct 'top' value would be. Using your example alone, that would be: the dynamic-div's top + the dynamic-div's height + any margins/other-spacing above.

Here's the code to make it happen (I included a basic fade so it's a little more seamless):

```
var marginOffset = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    marginOffset = $('#DynamicDivs').offset().top;
    $('#DynamicDivs div').mouseover(function(){
        $('#MainItemList').css({ position: 'fixed', top: $(this).position().top + $(this).height() + marginOffset}).stop(false, true).fadeIn('fast');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#MainItemList').stop(false, true).css({ display: 'none', position: 'static' });
    });
});
```

I have NOT tested this across multiple mobile devices, so do your due testing please. However, this method should be significantly less taxing on mobile devices than the appending html method.

Furthermore, this only handles the pop-up with scrolling. If you wish to have the pop-up list be delayed before it disappears, or if you have some complex margins, you'll have to revise the code accordingly.

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wXKfv/10/

EDIT:
After further discussion in the comments, here is the Javascript that solves the specific problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#DynamicDivs div').mouseover(function(){
        $('#MainItemList').css({ position: 'absolute', top: $(this).position().top + $(this).height()}).stop(false, true).fadeIn('fast');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#MainItemList').stop(false, true).css({ display: 'none', position: 'static' });
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wXKfv/11/

Comment: Thanks Daniel but the problem is while we scroll, dynamically created divs also scroll with it means it's like your text content in JSfiddle which moves along with scroll and that's the worse issue as I said in my question. Anyway thanks for kind support.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood... you mentioned that the divs scroll and that's important. I didn't realize it was important that they stop scrolling.

That's easily changed though in the JSFiddle example. Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/wXKfv/11/

Is this closer to what you want? If not, please let me know once again what you need, but even more specific. It's not as clear to us as to you what behavior you want.

Comment: WOW! Awesome man. It's really what I was looking for. I can't believe that it is solved. Thanks Man Thanks Alot. We were working on it for a long time but that's a simple solution thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. I know you already marked this as solved, but after further review, the code could be even simpler (moved 'position:absolute' to CSS, removed the unnecessary 'position:static'): http://jsfiddle.net/wXKfv/12/ Alternately, you don't need that fade at all, provided you add 'display:block': http://jsfiddle.net/wXKfv/13/

Comment: Thankx Daniel Thanks Alot. I really love your kind support. Thanks alot This is even great. Might I could give you 100 ups :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Put the MainItemList and DynamicDivs in to separate divs. Instead if appending to the existing div try replacing the MainListDiv. or put an .empty() before append()

-or-

Assuming you are loading the MainListDiv via ajax:

1. load the MainListDiv on to the body and hide it.
2. on click event for "DynamicDivs div" position the div with jquery and css under the DynamicDivs

Comment: Exactly That's the problem with option number 2. Look Anuradha suppose I have created a MainItemList div on page load and is hidden by diffault. Then an ajax is made and few divs are retrieved from server. Now how can I place with (Jquery or CSS) my MainItemList div just below any of those divs (which are ajaxed) I have clicked?

Comment: By placement you mean as a floating div or some other method ? 

If a floating div: you might wanna look at jquery position() and offset()

Did you try adding empty() to your code?

$(this).empty().append(MainListDiv);

Comment: Yes as a floating div. And I tried positioning it with Jquery but the problem is that as I said in question, if the div is floating and on click on div, it comes down to dynamically created div but when a user scrolls page floating div stays at where it was while dynamically created div moves along with scroll

Comment: How about applying the same positioning function on window scroll event ? That's how tool tip plugins work

Comment: Anuradha check Daniel's answer, it's exactly what I wanted. He has given JSfiddle also